# VBA get all hyperlinks in word document

Tags: vba, hyperlink, ms-word

I'm trying to update all hyperlinks in a word document with a macro using Visual Basic. My code updates only the hyperlinks that are not inside a text-box and those inside will not be changed. How can I change all the hyperlinks, including those that are inside any text-boxes as well?
I use this code to get my hyperlinks:

```
 Sub UpdateLinks()
  Dim oLink As Hyperlink
  links = 0
  For Each oLink In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
    oLink.Range.Bold = 0
    oLink.Range.Italic = 0
    oLink.Range.Underline = wdUnderlineNone
    oLink.Range.Font.Color = wdColorWhite
    oLink.Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorGray375
    links = links + 1
  Next oLink
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
Dim links As Integer
Sub UpdateLinks()
    links = 0
    UpdateDocLinks
    UpdateTextBoxLinks
End Sub
Sub UpdateDocLinks() 
    Dim oLink As Hyperlink
    For Each oLink In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
      links = links + FormatLink(oLink)
    Next oLink
End Sub
Sub UpdateTextBoxLinks()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim oLink As Hyperlink
    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count
        ActiveDocument.Shapes(i).Select
        For Each oLink In Selection.Hyperlinks
            links = links + FormatLink(oLink)
        Next oLink
    Next i
End Sub

Function FormatLink(link As Hyperlink) As Integer
     With link.Range
         .Bold = 0
         .Italic = 0
         .Underline = wdUnderlineNone
         .Font.Color = wdColorWhite
         .Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorGray375
      End With
      FormatLink = 1
End Function
```

DRY versions

```
Dim links As Integer
Sub UpdateLinks()
    links = 0
    UpdateDocLinks
    UpdateTextBoxLinks
End Sub
Sub UpdateDocLinks()
    UpdateLinkSet ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
End Sub
Sub UpdateTextBoxLinks()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count
        ActiveDocument.Shapes(i).Select
        UpdateLinkSet Selection.Hyperlinks
    Next i
End Sub
Sub UpdateLinkSet(link_set As Variant)
    Dim oLink As Hyperlink
    For Each oLink In link_set
        FormatLink oLink
    Next oLink
End Sub
Sub FormatLink(link As Hyperlink)
    With link.Range
       .Bold = 0
       .Italic = 0
       .Underline = wdUnderlineNone
       .Font.Color = wdColorWhite
       .Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorGray375
    End With
    links = links + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, so you created another function that goes thrue all the shapes and looks for hyperlinks in there. Why did you make some of them as Sub and some as Function?

Comment: Functions return a value so to be more concise I told it to return 1 for each link it formatted. I could have put links inside the function and changed it to a sub routine and just called FormatLink(oLink) which actually would have been more DRY. I can edit the response if you'd like to see that.

Comment: Added it anyway just so you can see