# Change display text of all hyperlinks in document

Tags: vba, hyperlink, ms-word

Im pretty much void of visual basic knowledge but I know this can be done some how. 
I have a 144 page document where I need to have the url be displayed. 
For example: where an inserted link displaying "Google" will now display: "Google (www.google.com)"

There are some 200+ links in this document (originally was suppose to just be an electronic document) but now need to have it so that if someone had a printed copy in hand they would know the URL. I'm open to all sorts of ideas :(

One thought I had was to do Alt F9 to view the field codes and then somehow do a find replace and input some sort of code to have the display text and the url show?

Earlier I had someone who had some visual basic knowledge trying to help with who found this which I couldn't get to run for me... Is it my lack of understanding on how to make it run?

```
    'Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

    Public Sub GetHyperlinks()
    Dim myDoc As Document
    Dim wombat As Hyperlink
    '    Dim starttime As Long
    Dim CurrentDoc As Document

    Applicationhttp://images.intellitxt.com/ast/adTypes/icon1.png.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set CurrentDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set myDoc = Application.Documents.Add()

'    starttime = GetTickCount
    For Each wombat In CurrentDoc.Hyperlinks
        myDoc.Range.InsertAfter wombat.TextToDisplay & vbTab & wombat.Address & vbCrLf
    Next
'    Debug.Print GetTickCount - starttime

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    myDoc.Range.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Add CentimetersToPoints(7.5), wdAlignTabLeft, wdTabLeaderSpaces 'basic formatting
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you (tested in Word 2010):

```
Sub UpdateDocLinks()
    Dim link As Hyperlink
    For Each link In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
        link.TextToDisplay = link.TextToDisplay & " (" & link.Address & ")"
    Next link
End Sub
```

This will append the URL in parenthesis to every active hyperlink in the document:

> [Google](http://www.google.com) becomes [Google (http://www.google.com)](http://www.google.com)

Comment: If you want to change the formatting of the link to remove the underline or blue color, that's possible too. I used [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035119/vba-get-all-hyperlinks-in-word-document) as a reference, it has some good info.

Comment: Holy smokes batman! This place is amazing! Thank you so much this just made my night and rest of week much easier!!

Comment: No problem! Glad to help. There's a lot of low-quality questions from new users on here and it's nice to see one like yours that is reasonably explained and discusses some things you've already tried or considered. (Btw, mind voting up my answer, too?)